# SQL Server : fix misspelled business names

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm looking for advice on how to tackle the issue of different spelling for the same name.
I have a SQL Server database with company names, and there are some companies that are the same but the spelling is different.

For example:

```
Building Supplies pty
Buidings Supplies pty
Building Supplied l/d
```

The problem is that there are no clear consistencies in the variation. Sometimes it's an extra 's', other times its an extra space.

Unfortunately I don't have a lookup list, so I can't use Fuzzy LookUp. I need to create the clean list.

Is there a method that people use to deal with this problem?

p.s I tried searching for this problem but can't seem to find a similar thread

Thanks

Comment: We've had these issues for years - tried educating our users, adding auto-complete fields when adding new companies... But still users manage to get duplicates in. Now we run a manual search once in a while to clean out duplicates! :(

Comment: Plus, you can never be sure if something is a duplicate or not. Business names are *very* diverse and new subsidiaries with a similar name keep popping up on a daily basis, for tax reasons or whatever else. You can never be sure if you "correct" something that was not really wrong in the first place. Be very careful.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`SOUNDEX()`  `DIFFERENCE()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187384.aspx) for this purpose.

```
DECLARE @SampleData TABLE(ID INT, BLD VARCHAR(50), SUP VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @SampleData 
SELECT 1, 'Building','Supplies'
UNION
SELECT 2, 'Buidings','Supplies'
UNION
SELECT 3, 'Biulding','Supplied'
UNION
SELECT 4, 'Road','Contractor'
UNION
SELECT 5, 'Raod','Consractor'
UNION
SELECT 6, 'Highway','Supplies'

SELECT *, DIFFERENCE('Building', BLD) AS DIF  
FROM @SampleData
WHERE DIFFERENCE('Building', BLD) >= 3
```

**Result**

```
ID  BLD         SUP        DIF
1   Building    Supplies    4
2   Buidings    Supplies    3
3   Biulding    Supplied    4
```

If this serves your purpose you can write an update query to update selected record accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the SOUNDEX() DIFFERENCE() option (which is a very good one btw!) you could look into SSIS more.

Provided your data is in english and not exclusively names of people there is a lot you can do with these components:

Term extraction

Term lookup

Fuzzy grouping

Fuzzy lookup

The main flow would be a tiered structure where you try to find duplicates at increasingly less certain ways. Instead of applying them automaticaly you send all the names and keys you would need to apply the changes to a staging area where they can be reviewed and if needed applied.

If you go about it really smart you can use the reviewed data as a repository for making the package "learn", for example iu is hardly ever valid in english so if that is found and changing it to ui makes a valid english word you might want to start applying those automaticaly at some point.

One other thing to consider is keeping a list of all validated names and use this to check for duplicates of that names and to prevent unnecesary recursion/load on checking the source data.